Are these versions of the Cramer Rao bound in matrix version the same?
Introduction and notation
The Cramér-Rao bound for a single parameter is given by
$$\text{var}(\hat\theta)\geq\frac{1}{J(\theta)},$$
where $\theta$ is a parameter of interest of some PDF $f(X;\theta)$, $\hat\theta(X)$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$, $\text {var}$ is the variance and $J(\theta)$ is ofcourse the Fisher information, given by
$$J(\theta)=\mathbb E\left[\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\log f(X;\theta) \right)^2\right].$$
When you want to generalize to multiple parameters, the Fisher information is promoted to a matrix. Given by
$$J_{ij}(\theta)=\mathbb E\left[\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_i}\log f(X;\theta) \right)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}\log f(X;\theta) \right)\right].$$
Problem
In the book Elements of Information Theory (Cover & Thomas) as well as on the corresponding Wikipedia article, the generalization of the Cramér Rao is stated as
$$\text{cov}(\hat \theta,\hat\theta)\succeq J^{-1}(\theta).\tag{1}$$
Here $A\succeq B$ means that $A-B$ is positive semi-definite and $\text{cov}$ is the covariance.
In Detection, Estimation, and Modulation Theory (H. Trees) I found the additional bound
$$\text{var}(\hat\theta_i)\geq(J^{-1})_{ii}\tag{2}$$
in the section that generalizes the Cramér-rao bound to multiple parameters, but he does not name it as such. In the same section he also mentions the first bound.
My question is, are these two bounds related? Does one imply the other? Can they be considered the same even??

If $e_i$ is the unit vector with all coordinates except the $i$th $0$, then $e_i^\top M e_i = M_{ii}$ for any matrix $M$. As a result, (1) implies that $(\mathrm{Cov}(\hat\theta, \hat\theta) - J^{-1}(\theta))_{ii} \ge 0,$ which is (2).

@stochasticboy321 that's much simpler than I thought! If you post it as an answer I will accept it.
